# Can't enable a new Anti-Virus (Kaspersky)

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, kaspersky

I just installed W10 and there is an error message saying that the AV software is disabled. I open the AV software list and i see Windows Defender and Kaspersky. If I click on WD, there is an option "Enable". But if I click on Kaspersky, there isn't. I CAN'T enable Kaspersky. it happens frequently after booting the system. Sometimes it works, sometimes it's de-activated. It doesn't seems to be a virus (I always had an AV software), probably it's a W10 bug (It's better than W8, but it's still any good).
I hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: A quick google scan found this, which appears to answer your question: https://usblog.kaspersky.com/windows-10-compatibility/

Comment: I already re-installed it after W10 upgrade. I had this problem sometimes also with W8

Comment: What version are you using specifically?

Comment: The version is 15.0.2.361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT*
You should be able to install the 2016 version of the program :) if not let me know!

Before installing Kaspersky Antivirus; remove any previous versions of Kaspersky or any other antivirus programs:

Windows 10:
-Go to the bottom of the screen to where it says search this computer; from there you will type in control panel and click on the first icon.

-If you have more than two lists then please find the bottom of the left hand side and it will say uninstall a program. IF NOT, and you have more than one list, please find the option programs and features.

-You should see a list of all the programs installed on your computer, find Kaspersky – right click & select change/uninstall.

Uninstall any other security software that may be on your PC.

Restart your computer.

I have included these to make sure that it is the correct download.
Direct downloads: (Remember to save, Not run when downloading, and do not install over the top of the old one)
http://www.kaspersky.com/au/downloads/anti-virus

Standard installation instructions of Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2016:
http://support.kaspersky.com/11999

Hope this helps!

Comment: After some months the problem randomly disappeared, i don't know what caused the problem, but yes, the time fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: The new update was working fine, finally

Comment: What happens with the Win10 update, is that the Kaspersky application breaks. (Kind of like if you took the engine out of your car, and then tried to drive it.) 
Sometimes with some of the Windows patches this is fixed, but its not very often it does. But I'm glad to hear that its been fixed for you!